# Why am i only getting towards else statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, call, private, encapsulation

**Please check the following programs and point out the mistake. I am getting "not ok" as result no matter whatever the input is.**

```
package timePass;
public class TimePass{
private String password;

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

    public void setPassword() {
        password="no";
        }
    }
```

```
package timePass2;

import java.util.Scanner;

import timePass.TimePass;

public class TimePass2{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimePass obj= new TimePass();
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        String p= sc.nextLine();
        TimePass tp= new TimePass();

        if(p.equals(tp.getPassword())) {System.out.println("ok");}
        else {System.out.println("not ok");}

    }
}
```

Comment: Just a hint: Either use an IDE (like IntelliJ or  Eclipse) and ___debug your program execution___ or do the poor-man's debugging by printing out the values involved in the assignment of the boolean variable ``woo``. In particular, ask youself what's the value returned by ``tp.getPassword()`` and why is that?

Comment: Note that the community here doesn't replace other great online resources such as [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) or reading books on Java programming. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also check out the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password for `tp` has not been set. You have to explicitly call `tp.setPassword()`, otherwise `tp.password` is `null`

Comment: could you please elaborate? I am a beginner and still not getting your point.

Comment: Do you know what a default constructor does and where you called it?

Comment: a default constructor is an auto-generated constructor that sets a null value.

Comment: Where I called it? I think i should still focus on constructor. :(

Comment: You wirte: "a default constructor is an auto-generated constructor that sets a null value." Do you get it now? If no, then insert `System.out.println(tp.getPassword());` right after `TimePass tp= new TimePass();` in the original code and you'll see it

Comment: oh! thank you so much.